# Polling for a url in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, polling

I am writing a Systray app that polls to see if a particular url is open in IE, and pops up a notification if it is detected.

It doesn't need to be realtime, just needs to detect if the page is open and prompt for an action.

What is the most efficient way to poll in this manner? I already put together some code to check if the site is open:

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
        string filename;
        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
        {
            filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();
            if (filename.Equals("iexplore"))
            {
                string[] urlParts = (ie.LocationURL.ToString()).Split('/');
                string website = urlParts[2];
                if (website == "myapp:8080") { appOpen = true; };
            }
        }
```

If appOpen returns true, the notification should be triggered.

I guess I'll need to thread this, as there is also a menu on the app. I want this to be as small a resource footprint as possible. Alternatively if there's some watcher I can use, this may be a better way. (Although I also need to check Chrome browser, too.

Comment: So, you have some code that seems to work. What is the question?

Comment: I have the code to do the test, but don't know the best way to have this continually polling. (i.e. At the moment it will run once and that's it. I want it to be continually checking if the url is open.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Timer` and integrates your code aiming to check for the URL in the timer tick. Of course, if the URL is opened then closed between to ticks of your timer, you won't know it.